# Get value out of an object

Tags: c++

I want to get the value of an object (the title was such a spoiler).

That object **may be a pointer or not**. I was searching for an STL function that would be the "invert counterpart" of `std::decay`

What I have so far looks like this :

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<T>::value, 
typename std::add_reference<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::type>::type 
deref(T val) 
{ return *val; } // lets call it the * policy

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<T>::value, 
typename std::add_reference<T>::type>::type 
deref(T& val) 
{ return val; } // lets call it the plain policy
```

Ofcourse these are used inside class templates where `T` is a parameter. I'm on purpose avoiding the use of `decltype` and friends to have things implementable in C++03 :(

**Is there a better, more consise way ? 
Will this solution "scale" to C++11 `&&`s ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just overload the function for pointers and non-pointers, there's no need to use SFINAE or type traits:

```
template<typename T>
  T& deref(T* val) 
  { return *val; }

template<typename T>
  T& deref(T& val) 
  { return val; }
```

For perfect forwarding just use a forwarding reference and `std::forward` instead of the second overload:

```
template<typename T>
  T&& deref(T&& val) 
  { return std::forward<T>(val); }
```

Comment: And for C++03, add a `T const&` overload.

Comment: It works without a const overload, the overload taking a reference will deduce `T` as a `const` type

Comment: That's helpful. I'm under the impression that if `T` is a `U&` type (a reference type) this will have problems. I also tried something similar and that's why I ended up with all the `remove_ref` stuff.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Not for (p)rvalues, unless they are `const`. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5d77ce7c0cb738d)

Comment: Ah yes, of course. So it does need another overload to handle that case then.

Comment: @dyp Yet, for the whole lot to work, we'd have to delete the `T&` overload, keep the `T const&` and `T&& val` (and `T*` ofcourse) or else the deducable context would produce two identical signatures for `T&` and `T&&` in case of lvalues

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou .. of which the `T&` is more specialized (so it would work with both `T&` and `T&&`). But it isn't necessary; the `T const&` and `T&` is only required in C++03.

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou, stop trying to make it more complicated than it needs to be :)

Comment: @JonathanWakely I'm implementing this in a range of compilers from VS10 to VS12, to gcc.4... to gcc of today. I'm not deliberately doing anytning more complicated, just reporting what's omniworking and what's not :) Apart from that I wouldn't find keeping both `T&` and `T&&` overloads a best practice, only one's needed